# Edit error on AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My `AndroidManifest.xml` has an error:

```
<activity
    android:name="bla.bla.Activity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_" >
</activity>
```

That activity doesn't exist anymore nor the string.
Since I can't edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it would regenerate that code again, how can I fix this?

PS: Already tried cleaning the project a few times. Using Windows.

Comment: *Since I can't edit the AndroidManifest.xml* how come? Are you editing the generated manifest maybe?

Comment: You can't edit the AndroidManifest.xml anymore? What? Why?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, You're right. Android Studio opens the generated one instead of the actual one, that's shy I couldn't edit. Now I feel silly.
Could you post that as answer so I could mark as answered?

Comment: @TimCastelijns, yes.

Comment: Since this is a problem that **can** be reproduced and I couldn't find a duplicate, I figured I'd add an answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Since I can't edit the AndroidManifest.xml and it would regenerate that code again, how can I fix this?*

It very much sounds like you are editing the generated Manifest in the `gen/` folder instead.
If you make the changes to the 'regular' Manifest, it should work.

If you use the default Android Studio project structure, the one you need to open is

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Android Studio shouldn't open the generated one to point out the error. I was trying to edit there and, of course, couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a bug of Android Studio. I pressed `File > Invalidate > Invalidate and Restart`, then reopened Android Studio, and AndroidManifest became editable.

Answer (score 0):

i had this a problem before , you can open the AndroidManifest.xml by Notepade and edit , it will work

Answer (score 0):

I had manualy find the AndroidManifest.xml that was in app>src>main   folder...then Open it with notepad++ or Brackets (like he said)and then delete line :   android:theme="@Style/AppTheme"
Then no error appear.